# Showing div onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

What am i doing wrong here.. I'm trying to display the called sub div through js and css after clicking the links.
But it wont change at all.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="sub1">content 1</div>
    <div id="sub2" class="hide">content 2</div>
    <div id="sub3" class="hide">content 3</div>

    <div id="navigation">
        <a href="#" class="mininav" onclick="switchContent('sub1'); return false;">link 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="mininav" onclick="switchContent('sub2'); return false;">link 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="mininav" onclick="switchContent('sub3'); return false;">link 3</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
function switchContent(obj) {

        obj = (!obj) ? 'sub1' : obj;

        var contentDivs = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('div');
        for (i=0; i<contentDivs.length; i++) {
            if (contentDivs[i].id && contentDivs[i].id.indexOf('sub') != -1) {
                contentDivs[i].className = 'hide';
            }
        }
        document.getElementById(obj).className = '';

    }
```

CSS:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your javascript code **before** your html code, so the `onclick` function of your html code can find the `switchContent()` function.

Comment: it seems that this is the problem. Cause for me that script works fine except `switchContent` is undefined

Comment: I allready did that :)
And the script is tested here: http://jsfiddle.net/FPCWD/16/
without working :(

Comment: @Mathias, http://jsfiddle.net/FPCWD/17/ You use `onload` option in your fiddle. You need to do what the answer points, and do not wrap your function in the `onload` handler

Comment: Yeah, using **no wrap head** in jsfiddle is necessary for the javascript to be before the html. From jsfiddle docs --> **no wrap(head):**
do not wrap the JavaScript code, place it in <head> section

Answer (score 0):

why not using Jquery ?

```
$('subXX').hide();
```